# What is <%= or <%: called in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have been trying to figure out what to call the '<%=' and '<%:' output operators in asp.net.  Searching for symbols in google doesn't do much.

Comment: Don't know what search engine ya used, copied and pasted your question title to Google and got loads of answers :).

Comment: Nobody is answering the question: what are they "called"...

Comment: Stop voting for a close, its not a duplicate, user is asking to know what they are called, not what they do.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found good terminology here: [ASP.NET Page Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fy30at8h%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Microsoft calls these *Code Render Blocks*.

Answer (score 4):

`<%=` is `Response.Write`

`<%:` is `Response.Write` with `Server.Encode`

Answer (score 1):

These are affectionately known as "code nuggets"

http://dustinkendall.blogspot.com/2010/08/aspnet-mvc-code-nuggets.html

Comment: This is "incorrect". One blogger's personal colloquialism does not constitute an answer for everyone. :-) See above reference to Microsoft for a little more authoritative answer.

Comment: @BenSwayne - what part of "affectionately known as" don't you understand?  This is not "one blogger".  Google it, and you will find many many references, I just provided one link as a reference, would you prefer I list all 2,000+ references?

Comment: @BenSwayne - By the way, Even the program manager for ASP.NET (Scottgu) refers to them as Code Nuggets.  See where he refers to "New <%: %> Code Nugget Syntax" http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx and here by Phil Haack "code block (often called a Code Nugget by members of the Visual Web Developer team) syntax" http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/24/html-encoding-code-nuggets.aspx .. do I really need to keeo going?

Comment: Woah, don't let this ruin your day man. Those are certainly *more* authoritative resources you provided to support your answer than what you initially provided. However, **MSDN is still *the* authoritative source**. Guys like ScottGu and Phil Haack certainly help propagate colloquialisms all the time with the reach of their blogs - but MSDN still trumps for the best or most authoritative answer IMHO. But never mind me, watch the votes here and let the community's voice be heard.

Comment: @BenSwayne - again.  What part of "affectionately known as" makes you think I was saying it was an official name?  That phrase means it's what people call it unofficially.